# How to get home view in appcompat.v7

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbaractivity

I´m using ActionBarActivity and trying to get the position of the home button (burger) using:

```
View home = findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.home);
```

and/or

```
View home = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
```

The problem is I always get null.
Anyone know how to get the view? Maybe I´m trying to get it from the wrong place

I´m trying to get it from OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Comment: You have to use R of your app root package, not Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow the NikolasDespotoski code and I´m able to get it now

[Code here](http://translate.google.com.br/translate?hl=pt-BR&sl=en&tl=pt&u=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github.com%2Fbb963f9b8f40beb954a0&anno=2)

Thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

View home = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
```

Comment: I´m doing like this: getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); and getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: No. I´m in ActionBarActivity

Comment: throws a nullpointer exception :P That´s because I´m using supportActionBar I can´t call ActionBar.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid code disappearing in the future, I just copied from the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/bb963f9b8f40beb954a0) provided by @rendellhb

```
public class ToolbarNavigationUtil {
    public static View getToolbarNavigationIcon ( Toolbar toolbar ){
        //check if contentDescription previously was set 
        boolean hadContentDescription = TextUtils. isEmpty(toolbar.getNavigationContentDescription());
        String contentDescription = !hadContentDescription ? toolbar.getNavigationContentDescription().toString() : "navigationIcon" ;
        toolbar . setNavigationContentDescription(contentDescription);
        ArrayList< View > potentialViews = new ArrayList< View >();
        //find the view based on it's content description, set programatically or with android:contentDescription 
        toolbar . findViewsWithText(potentialViews,contentDescription, View . FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION );
        //Nav icon is always instantiated at this point because calling setNavigationContentDescription ensures its existence 
        View navIcon = null ;
        if (potentialViews . size() > 0 ){
            navIcon = potentialViews . get( 0 ); //navigation icon is ImageButton 
        }
        //Clear content description if not previously present 
        if (hadContentDescription)
            toolbar . setNavigationContentDescription( null );
        return navIcon;
    }

    public static TextView getToolbarTitleView ( ActionBarActivity activity , Toolbar toolbar ){
        ActionBar actionBar = activity . getSupportActionBar();
        CharSequence actionbarTitle = null ;
        if (actionBar != null )
            actionbarTitle = actionBar . getTitle();
        actionbarTitle = TextUtils . isEmpty(actionbarTitle) ? toolbar . getTitle() : actionbarTitle;
        if ( TextUtils . isEmpty(actionbarTitle)) return null ;
        // can't find if title not set 
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < toolbar . getChildCount(); i ++ ){
            View v = toolbar . getChildAt(i);
            if (v != null && v instanceof TextView ){
                TextView t = (TextView) v;
                CharSequence title = t . getText();
                if ( ! TextUtils . isEmpty(title) && actionbarTitle . equals(title) && t . getId() == View . NO_ID ){
                    //Toolbar does not assign id to views with layout params SYSTEM, hence getId() == View.NO_ID 
                    //in same manner subtitle TextView can be obtained. 
                    return t;
                }
            }
        }
        return null ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, worked for me.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
Log.d("checksize",toolbar.getChildCount()); \\print 1, this child is title
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
Log.d("checksize",toolbar.getChildCount()); \\print 2
View navIcon = toolbar.toolbar.getChildAt(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Use a style that extends "NoActionBar" as the activity's theme
2. Create a toolbar in the activity's layout file

Then query the home button this way

Using **Kotlin**:
val image = toolbar.getChildAt(1) as AppCompatImageButton

Using **Java**:
AppCompatImageButton imageButton = (AppCompatImageButton)toolbar.getChildAt(1)